# Null Pointer Exception while communicating between servlets

Tags: java, servlets

I have login code in one servlet:LoginGtalkServlet..

```
 XMPPConnection connection;

 //@see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)


 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String userName = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    System.out.println(userName);
    System.out.println(password);

    //ProxyInfo proxyInfo = new      
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com",5222,"gmail.com");
    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
    try {
        connection.connect();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        connection.login(userName, password);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    boolean status=connection.isAuthenticated();
    if(status==true)
    {
        System.out.println("Success");
        response.sendRedirect("GetRoster");
    }
    else
    {
        response.sendRedirect("Loginfailed.html");
    }
```

And my GetRosterServlet has the code for retreving the roster list

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
     Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
    for (RosterEntry r : entries) {
        String user = r.getUser();
        String name = r.getName();
        System.out.println(name + user);
    }
    roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
        // Ignored events public void entriesAdded(Collection<String>
        // addresses) {}
        public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {
        }

        public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {
        }

        public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
            System.out.println("Presence changed: " + presence.getFrom()
                    + " " + presence);
        }

        @Override
        public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {

        }
    });

}
```

Now the isssue is my GetRosterServlet is not informed that I haved logged into Gtalk..i.e LoginGtalkServlet is not communicating with GetRosterServlet and hence connection.getRoster() is throwing Null pointer exception...

How do I let the roster servlet know that the user is logged into gtalk and hence get the friends list

Comment: Exception StackTrace is very important, especially in NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I'm **not** familiar with XMPP/GTalk.

When you log in to it in `LoginGtalkServlet`, is it possible for you to be handed back some sort of session ID?  If so, you could put that into the redirect URL as a query parameter or in a POST body and then `GetRosterServlet` could extract the session ID from `request` and use it to Gtalk via that session ID.

(**Note**: the edit I just made was just to fix some bad grammar.  No substantive changes.)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the connection object in the session attribute.

```
session .setAttribute("connection", connectionObj);
```

And can get by using `session.getAttribute("connection");`

Comment: Is XMPPConnection *Serializable* ? .. (you shouldn't be storing non-serializable objects in session.